# Sorting in distinct data

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

on calling db.distinct() method always return the data in ascending order sorted. Is their a way I can get the data sorted in descending order?

Comment: If you want to sort it ou need to use $group in the aggregation framework instead

Answer (score 1):

The distinct command returns a javascript array, so you can always sort it and reverse it:

```
var array = db.coll.distinct("{field_name}")
array.sort()
array.reverse()
```

If using java driver, you can do something such as:

```
List list = coll.distinct("{field_name}");
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

Comment: Note that JS sorting is not always the fastest thing, plus no possibility ever of uisng indexes